# Strange problem regarding installation of budgie

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, budgie, rufus

I had no operating system on my Acer Aspire laptop. I just made a bootable USB with Rufus in my another Windows 7 PC for installing Ubuntu Budgie in my laptop. I installed it while trying it. Then it told me to restart as the installation was successfully completed. After the restart though the the USB was made to go down in the BIOS, once again the page saying "try Ubuntu", "install Ubuntu" blah blah blah appeared. I waited and automatically Ubuntu Budgie started. I again found the icon to install Ubuntu. I thought it happened because it automatically selected the option of trying without installing. So, I shut down the laptop and restarted without connecting the USB. But this time my PC acted as though there was no OS still then saying "checking media [failed]". I tried to install again. While going through the steps, it asked if I'd like to install it alongside it or reinstall it and stuffs like that meaning it was already installed, though I couldn't run it. I reinstalled and the same thing happened again but this time I didn't disconnect the USB and while I was in the trial room of the OS, I logged out to see what happens. A page appeared requiring my password and username. I thought for a moment "Hmm, Now I'm on the right track" but, when I put the right username and password, I couldn't log in because the password was according to the PC, invalid. The same problems happened again and again, yet, without the USB my Ubuntu doesn't work. And installing Ubuntu again and again "successfully" does no help for my PC. Help me and thanks before you do it!

Comment: It sounds like you installed it, in whole or in part, onto the usb.

Comment: Why'd that be, i installed it in a 600 gb memory as i noticed during the installs amd what about the password? @Organic Marble